# Get-AzureRMSubscription produces error after login with login-azurermaccount

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-5.0

I am trying to use get-azurermsubscription to get a list of available subscriptions in order to select one of five prior to running set-azurermcontext. I am getting the error:

> Method not found: 'Microsoft.Azure.Subscriptions.Models.SubscriptionListResult'

get-azurermcontext displays a valid tenatant id and valid subscription id, but of course does not display all of the subscriptions.

I downloaded the March 2015 Powershell installer to make sure everything was up to date, but have the same issues.

Just upgraded to VisualStudio 2015 update 2 and powershell v5. Have another machine with a similar configuration that works fine.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the Azure PowerShell version you're using?

Comment: Windows 10. $PSVersionTable.PSVersion = 5.0.10586.122 Nuget 2.8.5.127

Comment: I suspect you have a mismatched version of azureRM modules.  Make sure all PowerShell sessions are closed, open a new PowerShell window and run `install-module AzureRM -force` and see if this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment so doing it this way instead. On July 12 2016 AzureRM module received and update to version 1.6.0. I confirmed the cmd Get-AzureRMSubsctiption works from a Windows 10 machine.
[image]